# Need help combining two sql statements

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to find out how many clients were new and how many were returning for employees in a week.

To find out which clients the employee had last week, I query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ClientIdNumber FROM Transactions
 WHERE [Date] >= @startDate AND [Date] <= @endDate
 AND EmployeeIdNumber = @employeeIdNumber
```

To find out whether the client and employee has interacted before, I can query:

```
 IF (
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM Transactions
     WHERE [Date] < @startDate 
     AND ClientIdNumber = @clientIdNumber 
     AND EmployeeIdNumber = @employeeIdNumber
    ) > 0 
     SELECT 1 
  ELSE SELECT 0
```

I want to combine these queries into one so that the result-set looks like this:

EmployeeIdNumber - NewClients - ReturningClients

Using the two separate queries, I have to loop through the first result set and apply the second, which is of course very slow (and bad)

I can't get my head around it because I need the results from the first query in the second query, but I am sure there is a clever way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the fastest way to do it is:

```
with cte as (
    select distinct
        T.EmployeeIdNumber,
        T.ClientIdNumber,
        case
            when exists (
                select *
                from Transactions as TT
                where TT.[Date] < @startDate and TT.ClientIdNumber = T.ClientIdNumber
            ) then 1
            else 0
        end as Is_Old
    from Transactions as T
    where T.[Date] >= @startDate and T.[Date] <= @endDate
)
select
    EmployeeIdNumber,
    sum(case when Is_Old = 1 then 0 else 1 end) as NewClients,
    sum(case when Is_Old = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ReturningClients
from cte
group by EmployeeIdNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not fully clear to me what you mean by saying that the result-set should look like "EmployeeIdNumber - NewClients - ReturningClients". If you mean that you want for every `EmployeeIdNumber` to return the number of new clients and the number of returning clients, then here is my solution:

```
select
    t.EmployeeIdNumber,
    sum(case when t.count_before=0 then 1 else 0 end) as count_new_clients,
    sum(case when t.count_before>0 then 1 else 0 end) as count_returning_clients
from
    (
        select
            ClientIdNumber as ClientIdNumber,
            EmployeeIdNumber as EmployeeIdNumber,
            sum(case when [Date] >= @startDate and [Date] <= @endDate then 1 else 0 end) as count_last_week,
            sum(case when [Date] < @startDate then 1 else 0 end) as count_before
        from Transactions
        group by
            ClientIdNumber,
            EmployeeIdNumber
    ) t
group by
    t.EmployeeIdNumber
having
    t.count_last_week>0;
```